# Footer element displays on top of page with IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Working on a page for a nonprofit. The content is finished, working on cross-browser rendering. Huge problem with IE. I did get the content to mostly diplay correctly, but the footer element of the site, which should be at the bottom of the page, is displaying on the top of the site. How can I fix this? By the way, this is not the only display problem, just the topic for this question. I do not want to use any scripting.

Here is the website: http://www.ncalhn.org/testing/ncdba/events.html

Footer displays on the top of the page on IE only. I'm assuming IE doesn't recognize the footer element yet so looking for code to make IE understand the footer should be displayed at the bottom of the page. code currently using:

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 90px; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: absolute;
}

.foot {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<footer>
Follow us on social media!
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ncdba/" class="foot"><img src="http://ncdba.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/fb-art.png" alt="Facebook" width="50" height="50"/></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ncdeafblind" class="foot"><img src="http://ncdba.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/tw.jpeg" alt="Twitter" width="50" height="50"/></a>
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/NCDeafBlind/" class="foot"><img src="http://ncdba.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pinterest" width="50" height="50"/></a>
</footer>
```

Tried adding `bottom:0;` and then again with `margin-bottom: 0px;` and neither worked. Also tried changing between `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` - makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have your footer `position: absolute,` but no positional values.

Try adding `bottom: 0;` at least to the footer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that one. Would that be margin-bottom: 0;?

Comment: No literally just bottom: 0;  When you say position: absolute, you tell it where to go in relation to any parent that has position: relative. You do this by saying left: 13px, top: 5%, bottom: 0, etc

Comment: Tried that both literally and as margin-bottom and neither worked.